# Can't add to table of contents (using cuisine package, memoir class)

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir, package-options

According to [package documentation](http://repositorios.cpai.unb.br/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/cuisine/cuisine.pdf), adding "contents" as an argument should add the recipe titles to the TOC, but it's not working.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[nonumber, contents, index]{cuisine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
[...]
\pagebreak

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Lista de abreviaturas}
[...]
\mainmatter
[...]
\chapter{Massas e seus molhos}

\begin{recipe}{Massa de macarrão básica}{1 porção}{}
\ingredient[100]{g}{farinha de trigo}
\ingredient[1]{}{ovo}
[...]
\end{recipe}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! I guess we need to add `\end{document}` to get that to compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

or (thanks to [daleif's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386452/cant-add-to-table-of-contents-using-cuisine-package-memoir-class/386456?noredirect=1#comment957659_386456))

```
\settocdepth{subsection}
```

before `\begin{document}`. The package adds recipes as sub-sections, rather than sections, which is below the level which Memoir puts in the contents by default. Increasing that level solves the problem.

Comment: In memoir terms `\settocdepth{subsection} ` might be even easier to understand (does the same)

Comment: @daleif Thanks. I've edited with that line, which may well be easier, as you say. (I didn't know Memoir let you do that, so thanks for the information.)

Comment: Please read what I wrote and compare 